# Error Message in R - `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels

Tags: r

I am working with the Iris dataset, and my prediction and test factors continue to have different levels, and I am having a hard time resolving this.  Below is the code I am using:

['data' and 'reference' should be factors with the same levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGjLa.png)

I have used 'nlevels' to prove that these two tables are different, just not sure how to reconcile them:

[Different Levels example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyX9V.png)

I know that "iris_prediction" is a factor with three levels, while "iris_test$species" is a Character:

[Factor - 3 Levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgUo2.png)
[Character - Null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njIED.png)

> unique(iris_test$species)
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGjLa.png) "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" 
>   unique(iris_prediction)
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGjLa.png) setosa     versicolor virginica 
>   Levels: setosa versicolor virginica

Can someone help me out with what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you not just convert the character string into factors via `as.factor()`? i.e. `iris_test$species <- as.factor(iris_test$species)`

Comment: That worked, thanks!